# Simple login in Python3

Tags: python

Hi I am a uni student and this is the first time I am taking a programming subject. I am struggling to create a simple login program that takes two inputs and checks if there is a successful login combination.

Here is the code Ive got so far... thanks in advance for any help!

```
#Inputs username and password

#If the inputs match the accounts
    #Outputs "welcome back <username>"

#If the inputs dont match the accounts
    #Output "Wrong username or password"

#Initialising variables
use1 = "alice"
use2 = "bob"
use3 = "carol"

ans1 = "greenfingers"
ans2 = "builder"
ans3 = "danvers"

login1 = input("Username: ")
login2 = input("Password: ")

if (login1 == use1 or use2 or use3):  
    if (login2 == ans1 or ans2 or ans3):
        print("Welcome back {}".format(login1))
        
else: 
    print("Wrong username or password")
```

Comment: This current structure allows any user to login with any password.  Probably not the most ideal solution.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `or`  in this way, you need write a condition

```
if (login1 == use1 or login1 == use2 or login1 == use3):  
    if (login2 == ans1 or login2 == ans2 or login2 == ans3):
        print("Welcome back {}".format(login1))
        
else: 
    print("Wrong username or password")
```

Comment: Or, more concisely:  `login1 in (use1, use2, use3)`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use dictionary to simplify check condition and to get better lookup performance:

```py
user_passwords = {
    'alice': 'greenfingers',
    'bob': 'builder',
    'carol': 'danvers',
}

login = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")

if login in user_passwords and user_passwords[login] == password:
    print(f'Welcome back {login}')

else:
    print("Wrong username or password")
```

Answer (score 0):

for python format string = [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-string-format?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=278443377095&utm_targetid=aud-438999696719:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1029477&gclid=CjwKCAjwloCSBhAeEiwA3hVo_USmExoq4uU70ts-6PrvRwOkizpukrJ9QQtX-5QdsANdITBClvBWphoCnckQAvD_BwE)
and you can use 'in' instead of 'or'

```
use1 = "alice"
use2 = "bob"
use3 = "carol"

ans1 = "greenfingers"
ans2 = "builder"
ans3 = "danvers"

login1 = input("Username: ")
login2 = input("Password: ")

if ((login1 in [use1,use2, use3 ]) and (login2 in [ans1,ans2, ans3 ])):  
   
        print(f"Welcome back {login1}")
       
        
else: 
    print("Wrong username or password")
```